# Please, how do I request that a closed question be reopened?

Tags: support, appropriate-questions

My StackOverflow experience tells me that once a hold is put on a question it's very unlikely to ever be removed.  However, since this is English Language & Usage I wondered if there might be hope.  I've edited the question.  Now I ask if there is more I should do or if I should shut up and take the hold like a man.

[Section title for explaining where a subject fits into a field of study](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/264898/76689)

Answer (score 3):

As one of the closers, I can explain that I had no idea what you were asking for; I'm sorry about that.

As a non-programmer, I still have absolutely no idea what you're asking for. However, in it's edited form, even though I certainly can't figure it out, I usually don't vote to close such a question because there are plenty of programmers on this site who might have the answer.

So what you did is the right thing. When a question is put on hold, the correct thing to do is to edit it, and nominate it for reopening. If you're brave, you come to meta for support. It's not unusual here for a well-edited question, or one that is explained adequately, to be reopened.

I'll vote to reopen since I would not have VTC the question if asked in it's present form. If four other people understand it, think it's on topic, and think it's answerable, then mission accomplished.

Comment: I do appreciate this response.  However, since it's been 12 hours since the edit with no change.  I'm still wondering if there is more to do.  If there is more to clarify with an edit please let me know.  Barring that my only options seem to be flag for moderator attention (which is what I assume you mean by nominate), delete, or just walk away.

Comment: @CandiedOrange - Only 18 people viewed this request, and you have 2 reopen votes already. There little else to do; a flag on this will be declined. Besides, a mod (Matt E. Эллен♦) saw it and did not choose to reopen. Nominate means to click on the reopen option  (in grey to the left under your question.) Ask for support is what you've done here. You may very well get it reopened. I can't help you edit what I don't understand. Your only other option is to ask a programmer in chat. Remember, please, participation is voluntary; you can't make people help you.

Comment: I'm concerned that by the time the hold is removed (if it ever is) no one will be looking at the question anymore.  I'd vote to reopen as you suggest but that currently requires 250 reputation.  Mostly I want to understand how I can improve the question so people will want to help.

Comment: @CandiedOrange - Did you try going to chat?